# How to model database when fields are dependent of other data?

Tags: dependencies, relational-database

The story is like this:

*One* **Element** can be part of *many* **Projects**.

In *one* **Project** there can be *many* **Elements**.

...

*One* **Element** can be of *one* **Type**.

From *one* **Type** there can be *many* **Elements**.

...

From the first 2 rules JOIN table appears **Project_Elements**.

Depending on the **type**, there is different set of data fields that should be stored for the **Project_Elements** relation. How to model this?

For example, if the element is of **type** = number
then **Project_Elements** table should store data as:

tbl. **Project_Elements**

field_1

and if element **type** = letter
then **Project_Elements** table should store data as:

tbl. **Project_Elements**

field_A

field_B

field_C

Answer (score 0):

I thought of one answer;

Since the Types are given(number or letter) - table Element should be split on two: numberElement and letterElement. The rest is obvious.

If the Types were dynamic, or user defined, then it is other situation and then solution could look as this:

Element -m:n- Project
Element -n:1- Type
Type -n:1-DataStructure(definition of the data set)
Project_Element -n:1- DataStructure